# Search form has an Enum dropdown field whose value may be null (none selected) once it reaches my lambda Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, enums

Basically, if the user selected no option from the dropdown combo, I want it to be left out from my Linq query that looks something like this:

```
// this is how I manage the form post data, please 
// propose a better way if you know one
Dictionary<string, string> formdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    formdata.Add(key, Request.Form[key]);
}    

// getting the title
string title = "";
formdata.TryGetValue("postedTitle", out title);

// getting the level
string levelString = "";
formdata.TryGetValue("postedLevel", out levelString );

int level = -1;
if(levelString != "")
{
    Int32.TryParse(levelString , out level);
}


var model = new FooIndexVM
{
    Foos = _ctx.SomeDbSet.Where(w => w.Title.Contains(title) && w.Level == (Level?)level.Value).Select(x => new FooBarRow
            {
                FooBarId = x.Id,
                ....
```

Since I'm getting either `0` or `-1` for the `level` -- I need a way to gracefully leave the Enum part from the query completely. I will also later add some additional fields similar to this one (may be unselected) so the solution will also work for those, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain `Where` commands so this line:

```
Foos = _ctx.SomeDbSet.Where(w => w.Title.Contains(title) && w.Level == (Level?)level.Value).Select(x => new FooBarRow
            {
                FooBarId = x.Id,
                ....
```

Could be rewritten to be this without changing its behaviour (multiple `Where`s effectively become combined with `&&`s):

```
Foos = _ctx.SomeDbSet.Where(w => w.Title.Contains(title)).Where(w => w.Level == (Level?)level.Value).Select(x => new FooBarRow
            {
                FooBarId = x.Id,
                ....
```

This then means that you can add some logic around whether to apply the second `Where` or not like this, for example:

```
var query = _ctx.SomeDbSet.Where(w => w.Title.Contains(title));
if (level != -1)
{
  query = query.Where(w => w.Level == (Level?)level.Value)
}

Foos = query.Select(x => new FooBarRow
            {
                FooBarId = x.Id,
```

Comment: Great, it works. I wasn't aware the `where` clause is chainable. Thanks a bunch!